# How to change the way Connector Shape looks like when connected to other shapes?

Tags: python, python-pptx

I am trying to create PowerPoint presentations with python-pptx and currently I am trying to create shapes and connectors in a for loop. Even though the Connector is created and it does connect to shapes, it looks unnatural when I open the presentation itself, kinda like it's rotated. However, as soon as as I move the top of the shapes, its starts to look as expected.

I've tried reading documentation (https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shapes.html#connector-objects) but I don't see any option that changes the way Connector "looks".

Some of the code:

```py
top_shape = shapes.add_shape(MSO_SHAPE.RECTANGLE, Inches(2), Inches(1), width, height)
    for i in range(8):
    bottom_shape = shapes.add_shape(MSO_SHAPE.RECTANGLE, left, top, width, height)
    connector = shapes.add_connector(MSO_CONNECTOR.ELBOW, Cm(1), Cm(1), Cm(1), Cm(1))
    connector.begin_connect(top_shape, 2)
    connector.end_connect(bottom_shape, 0)
prs.save('test.pptx')
```

I expect it to look like here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/reroute-or-move-connectors-between-shapes-da6a1212-927b-4473-967d-484182f47b3f

[Here is how the presentation looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LctZL.png)

It seems it like, the "elbow" part is created in the 'horizontal' middle, rather than vertical. Is there any way to change how the elbow line looks like?

Comment: Was this issue solved? Would appreciate your guidance if so. Thanks!

Comment: @Rami.K Hi! Actually no, not with this library, I eventually stopped trying. I was however more successful with using pptxgenjs library for JavaScript. The library itself doesnt support all connector shapes, but I modified it for my usage and was able to create Connectors as they should look. In case this is an appropriate solution for you, I might find what I changed to make it work in my single case.